# laravel mix - no minification of the css with option processCssUrls:false

Tags: css, sass, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I use this code to compile sass to css.

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/my.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    })
    .version();
```

Without `processCssUrls: false` the compilation is extremely slow (30sec), and I don't need this feature, so I set the option -- no problem.

My problem is, that the resulting css is not minified. Am I doing something wrong or what could be the reason?

my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of laravel-mix to ^0.9.2, it's fixed.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/612